# Information about "JLR DoiP VCI WI-FI"

Tags: range-rover

Can anyone tell me more about below product: *"JLR DoiP VCI WI-FI"* <sup>1</sup>

- manufacturer (or alternatives?): I doubt it is made by Rover.
- what is it for: Yes, it is some sort of interface to connect accessories to the car, I might be using wrong search terms, need more specs about the product.
- where do I buy it: There is one on ebay, and other sites (see below), but not very confident to buy an expensive product then find out it is not what we need.

**Car:** Range Rover 2017 from [INKAS](https://inkasarmored.com/armored-range-rover/).

I have searched the net:

- [ebay](https://www.ebay.com/itm/GENUINE-JLR-DoiP-VCI-WI-FI-JAGUAR-LAND-ROVER-Pathfinder-Interface-Authentic-/263279722141?) says it is an interface.
- [bidiags.co.uk](https://www.bidiags.co.uk/store/p101/New%21______JLR-DOIP-VCI-Wi-Fi________New%21.html)
- [jaguar.service-solutions.com](https://jaguar.service-solutions.com/Detail/839/JLR-DOIP-VCI-WF-DOIP_VCI)

---

<sup>1</sup> First time post here, sorry if it doesn't fit with the site rules, kindly let me know and I will update/delete.

Comment: Welcome to the site @zx8754, I'm not sure what you are asking for. "Information" is very broad, what is it you need to know about it?

Comment: @GdD thanks, who makes them, and what is it used for? Any other info? Can't seem to find anything on the net, maybe there are other alternatives. Pretty sure I am using wrong search terms.

Comment: Perhaps you should be looking at the JLR original software if you need the "proper" solution as the aftermarket ones don't always do all the functions : and, yes I have an aftermarket one....

Comment: @SolarMike thanks, "yes I have an aftermarket one" do you mean you have the same product? Who makes them?

Comment: If I had the same one I would have said so... As I said I have one of the available aftermarkets ones and it is sufficient for my needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ebay link makes it clear it's a diagnostic unit which will interface with the car, it's for diagnosing engine problems and programming the car's computer, it has nothing to do with connecting accessories to the car. You'd buy it if you want to work on the Jaguar and Land Rover cars listed and need to read the codes, reset check engine lights, etc.

Rover is a separate manufacturer, so it's definitely not made by them.

Answer (score 3):

JLR - Jaguar Land Rover

DoIP - Diagnostic over IP (Internet Protocol)

VCI - Vehicle Communication Interface

WI-FI - Wireless Lan

JLR's new VCI (the diagnostic "box" between your computer and car) using Ethernet cable (Internet communication) plugged into the car. If there is an OBD socket on the car it needs a "mechanical" Ethernet-OBD adapter connecting the wires of Ethernet cable to some pins of the OBD connector.

It is why the old (cheap) OBD diagnostic VCIs and their connectors cannot used for JLR cars using DoIP interface. JLR cars with this new DoIP diagnostic socket/conector/interface started to appear from 2017.

Currently (end of 2018) there are only two types of DoIP interfaces: factory original, priced over 1000 EUR, and a Chinese clone about 600 EUR, which shows very good compatibility with the original one.

WIFI can be used for communication between your computer (running JLR new diagnostic SW named Pathfinder) and those special DoIP VCI box.

Answer (score 1):

Jaguar Land Rover DoIP VCI is the only unit that will be compatible with Pathfinder and all JLR vehicles with the new vehicle architecture (from the Range Rover/Range Rover Sport (L405/L494)17MY onwards) or allow the enhanced diagnostics that Pathfinder will offer the retailer addition to the 17MY vehicle line applications,the DolP VCI will be capable of interfacing of interfacing with 14-18MY Multi-CAN architecture vehicle lines on the Pathfinder diagnostic system Pre-14MY and vehicles not detailed here will continue to use the current diagnostic system and VCls.

https://www.cnautotool.com/goods-6655-JLR-DoiP-VCI-SDD-Pathfinder-Interface-for-Jaguar-Land-Rover-from-2005-to-2017.html